# How to connect our own app one account with another account?

Tags: flutter, dart

I hope i will find the great answer from you
I am currently working on an app i want that app to work remotely

For an instance,
I press a key in my app(account) it reflects in another app(account)

**Using flutter**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To connect one flutter app to another you need some way to access shared data ie a database, you can use a few different ones, firebase is a good start. your question is very vague.